# Proving a metric satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. We define a second metric $\psi: X \times X \to [0, \infty)$ given by

$$\psi(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1}$$

I would like to prove in particular that $\psi$ satsifies the triangle inequality. But it seems trickier than it would first appear. So far I've said

Let $x,y,z \in X$. Since $d$ is a metric, we know that

$$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$

My next step is to convert $d(x,z)$ into $\psi(x,z)$. So I divide everything by $d(x,z) +1$ and obtain

$$\psi(x,z) = \frac{d(x,z)}{d(x,z)+1} \leq \frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,z)+1} + \frac{d(y,z)}{d(x,z)+1}$$

At this point though, I stop. I'm not certain this is the proper way to approach this proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: dividing it all by a $d(x,z)+1$ does not convert $d(x,z)$ into $\psi(x,z)$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame why not

Comment: it should be each two variables over itself, not the $d(x,y)$ on top then $d(x,z)+1$ on bottom.

Comment: what you want to show is that $\frac{d(x,z)}{d(x,z)+1}\leq \frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1}+\frac{d(y,z)}{d(y,z)+1}$